how to convert Intellij plugin to visual studio plugin
At present, the commonly used IDE has Visual Studio Eclipse  Intellij, if I want to develop plug-ins for these three ides, I have to write three sets of code.
I would like to know, whether there is a framework that can achieve a set of code to complete the plug-in development of multiple platforms
.
Like the current front-end framework Flutter, a set of code can generate small programs for web pages and mobile applications
Try：I searched on github for several well-known tools that provide plugins for the three platforms, but all are independent projects.
Expecting: I was hoping someone would recommend an open source framework that could implement my idea, or give me some ideas that could work

If you're looking for a framework that allows you to develop a plugin once, and then deploy it as an extension across Visual Studio 2022, IntelliJ IDEA, and Eclipse, then the answer should be NO.
There isn't a single out-of-the-box solution that supports all three IDEs seamlessly. The platform architecture between these three IDEs is very different, as are the APIs.
For these three different IDEs, there are only limited situations where they can share parts, such as LSP:
Language Server Protocol for Visual Studio
Language Server Protocol (LSP) for Intellij
Language Server Protocol for eclipse
But their respective extensions are still independent.
